# Prevent NSData to remove special characters

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdata, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to send a string data with NSData but i need that has a "+" on the message by example "hello +world", but when coming to the server, become with no + char "hello  world".

```
NSData *bodyData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[body UTF8String] length:[body length]];
[request setHTTPBody:bodyData];
```

I don't know what happened. i need to send special chars using this. any help?

Comment: A `+` in a URL is translated to a space (and visa-versa). That's normal behavior. Try using `%2B` instead of `+`.

Comment: i'm trying to send that + as body message, that's like a user message (comments), he can write any text.

Comment: NSData isn't altering anything. Perhaps `request` modifies it.

Comment: The above NSData operation will exactly preserve whatever is in `body` (though it would be simpler to just do `[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`).

Answer (score 0):

You are sending you message using GET method to you server. If you send using POST method you problem will be solve. Remember that when you send message for GET method it will be pass by the URL, and the " " (blank spaces) are replaced by "%20". I hope that it help you.

Comment: Hi, i'm sending a post method for this, but every time it remove the characters, this is what i doing. http://pastebin.com/giGsXPZk
(param=something&foo=bar+&data=this message contains &/(/( characters)

Comment: I did see your code, and I think that you are sending as GET method.